# Python: lxml xpath to extract content

Tags: python-2.7, lxml, lxml.html

Below code able to extract **PE** from the reuters link below. However, my method is not robust as the webpage for another stock has two lines lesser and result a shift of data. How can I encounter this problem. I would like to point straight to the part of PE to extract the data but do not know how to do it.
link 1: http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=MYEG.KL
link 2: http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=ANNJ.KL

```
from lxml import html
import lxml

page2 = requests.get('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=MYEG.KL')
treea = html.fromstring(page2.content)
tree4 = treea.xpath('//td[@class]/text()')
PE= tree4[37]
```

This is the part I wish that the code can extract only this part so that any changes of the webpage will not affected.

```
 <tr class="stripe">
                <td>P/E Ratio (TTM)</td>
                <td class="data">36.79</td>
                <td class="data">25.99</td>
                <td class="data">21.70</td>
            </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the text to find the first *td* then extract the sibling *td's*:

```
 treea.xpath('//td[contains(.,"P/E Ratio")]/following-sibling::td/text()')
```

That will work regardless:

```
In [8]: page2 = requests.get('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=MYEG.KL')

In [9]: treea = html.fromstring(page2.content)    
In [10]: tree4 = treea.xpath('//td[contains(.,"P/E Ratio")]/following-sibling::td/text()')

In [11]: print(tree4)
['36.79', '25.99', '21.41']

In [12]: page2 = requests.get('http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/financialHighlights?symbol=ANNJ.KL')
In [13]: treea = html.fromstring(page2.content)

In [14]: tree4 = treea.xpath('//td[contains(.,"P/E Ratio")]/following-sibling::td/text()')

In [15]: print(tree4)
['--', '25.49', '17.30']
```